# code works fine on localhost, but not on hostinger host provider - 3 days searching on internet and many attempts in vain so far

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[SCREEN SHOT ERROR 500 AFTER FIXING THE PATH AT AJAX CODE]
Not sure if there is ajax call problem or the path of resources files (jquery)

HEADER , BASICALLY I TRIED MVC, WHERE THE INDEX PAGE CONTAIN THE PATH TO ALL PAGES, HEADER, FOOTER, CONTROLLERS, FUNCTIONS, ACTIONS, CONNECTIONS...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

My Resources

```
<!-- datetimepicker
-->
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.3.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<!-- General CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style2.css" type="text/css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css?nocache={timestamp}" type="text/css">-->
```

my javascript...
FOOTER FILE

```
$("#LoginSignup").click(function() 
  {// alert ("hi5");}
 $.ajax(
{ type: "POST",
 url: "functions.php?action=LoginSignup",
 data: "useremail=" + $("#useremail").val() + "&password=" + $("#password").val() + "&loginActive=" + 
$("#loginActive").val() + "&firstname=" + $("#firstname").val() + "&cpassword=" + 
$("#cpassword").val() + "&lastname=" + $("#lastname").val() + "&phonenumber=" + 
$("#phonenumber").val(),
     success: function(result) {//alert ("hi");
       if (result == "1") 
        {//alert ("hei");
        $("#loginAlert").html('<div class="alert alert-primary">Well Done<p><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>').show(); 
        window.location.assign("http://localhost/14%20-%20Hairdresser/?page=home");
        } else
        { //alert ("hoi");

        }
      }
   })
  })
```

My Console errors:.. 
I AM BEGINNER, NOT SURE HOW TO DIG DEEPER INTO THE CONSOLE ERRORS YET

```
                  jquery.js:6 POST https://aquenzitech.com/functions.php?action=LoginSignup 404
    send    @   jquery.js:6
    ajax    @   jquery.js:6
    (anonymous) @   ?page=login:182
    dispatch    @   jquery.js:5
    v.handle    @   jquery.js:5
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jckn.png)

Comment: You tried to make a POST request to `https://aquenzitech.com/functions.php?action=LoginSignup`, but the server answered that with a 404 Not Found. So most likely you did not upload a file by that name to that location to begin with.

Comment: `window.location.assign("http://localhost/14%20-%20Hairdresser/?page=home");` – you did not actually upload that as production code onto the live website?

Comment: TKS CBroe! after fixing the path, got error 500, i will try to post a screenshot here

Comment: Then you need to go and check what the error log has to say about that first of all. If you don’t know where to find it, ask your hoster/check their FAQ.

Comment: @CBroe solved it !  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe mentioned in the comments on the post:

> You tried to make a POST request to `https://aquenzitech.com/functions.php?action=LoginSignup`, but the server answered that with a 404 Not Found. So most likely you did not upload a file by that name to that location to begin with.
>   `window.location.assign("http://localhost/14%20-%20Hairdresser/?page=home");` – you did not actually upload that as production code onto the live website?
>   Then you need to go and check what the error log has to say about that first of all. If you don’t know where to find it, ask your hoster/check their FAQ.

after moving all to absolute path and correcting some of the wrong paths, got everything running smooth!